# mysql 10.1 Foreign on cascade not working

Tags: sql, mariadb

```
CREATE TABLE keyList (key_ID integer NOT null AUTO_INCREMENT,
                      keyname varchar(255),
                      PRIMARY KEY (key_ID))
                      Engine = InnoDB;


CREATE TABLE userList (User_ID integer NOT null AUTO_INCREMENT,
                      name varchar(255),
              lastName varchar(255),
              email varchar(255),
              key_ID integer,
                      PRIMARY KEY (User_ID),
CONSTRAINT FK_keylist_key_ID
FOREIGN KEY (key_ID)
REFERENCES keyList (key_ID)
ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE)
Engine = InnoDB;
```

Mysql version is 10.1. I am working through Xampp 7.1.10. 
Once I try to delete one data from the `keylist` table it won't delete the corresponding `User_ID` row in the `userList`. When I check the foreign key it's written NULL. What am I doing wrong?
Thanks.

Comment: MySQL or MariaDB?.

Comment: Server type: MariaDB. Sorry if I am a total noob

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem, see [dbfiddle](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=8638d9f4443c9dd000611045c8c00a76).

Comment: I have installed an older release of Xampp and it seems to work. I have code you gave me.
Thank you very much!